# A characterization of constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integration, sobolev-spaces

In [*How to recognize constant functions. Connections with Sobolev spaces*](https://www.turpion.org/php/paper.phtml?journal_id=rm&paper_id=533) (Russian Math Surveys **57** (2002); [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1942116)), H. Brezis recalls the following fact:

> Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^N$ be connected and $f:\Omega\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ be measurable, such that 
>   $$\int\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}\frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{|y-x|^{N+1}}\,dx\,dy<\infty.$$
>   Then $f$ is constant.

He adds

> *The conclusion is easy to state, but I do not know a direct, elementary, proof. Our proof is not very complicated but requires an “excursion” via the Sobolev spaces.*

My question is whether there is such an elementary proof in the special case of one space dimension ($N=1$, $\Omega$ an interval).

Comment: I don't know about measurable functions, but here's a relatively easy proof for when $f$ is continuously differentiable. Suppose $f$ is not constant. Then $|f'(y)| > c > 0$ on some small interval. For each such $y$, we have $|f(y) - f(x)| > c|y-x|$ on a neighborhood of $y$. Then your integrand (for that particular $y$) is $>\! c/|y-x|$ on a neighborhood of $y$, and therefore goes to $\infty$. Since this happens for an interval of $y$'s, the whole double integral is also $\infty$.

Comment: Such a function $f$ is in $L^1_{loc}$. Assuming $\Omega=R^N$ we can take convolutions with smooth cut-off function $\phi_\epsilon$ and the integrability condition is preserved. Then $f*\phi_\epsilon$ is a constant (by the argument of @Will Brian) and letting $\epsilon \to 0$, $f$ is constant, as well. For general $\Omega$ this does not work, but in 1d $\Omega$ is an interval $[a,b]$ and we can extend $f$ outside, using the values at the endpoints. I did not check the details but maybe you see immediately if there is a silly mistake in the argument.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune What worries me in your argument is this: we start with a measurable function $f$ for which the double integral from the statement of the problem converges. How do you conclude, that the same holds for $f\ast\phi_\epsilon$?

Comment: @Vahe If $g=f*\phi$, then $\int |g(y)-g(x)|/|y-x|^{N+1} dy dx \le \int |f(y-z)-f(x-z)/|y-x|^{N+1}|\phi (z) dx dy dz$. Next write $|y-x|=|(y-z)-(x-z)|$ and change variables by setting $u=y-z, v=x-z$ in the $dx\, dy$ integral. Then you get the original double integral to be integrated against $\phi(z)\, dz$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune You're right, thanks!

Comment: It is here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488780/if-int-mathbb-r2-frac-vert-fx-fy-vert-vert-x-y-vert2dxdy-infty/545051#545051

Answer (score 9):

Not quite an answer, but too long for a comment.

Let me make my life easier a bit and take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^N$ while increasing the exponent slightly. Namely, I will assume that
$$
I:=\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\ d^Nx d^Ny
$$
is finite, where $\alpha>N+1$.
Then we have, just by the triangle inequality involving the midpoint, $I\le J$ where
$$
J:=\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\ 
\frac{\left|f(x)-f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right|
+\left|f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-f(y)\right|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\ d^Nx d^Ny
$$
$$
=\ 2^{N+1-\alpha}\ I\ ,
$$
by a trivial change of variable. Since $I\in [0,\infty)$ and $I\le 2^{N+1-\alpha}\ I$ with $N+1-\alpha<0$, we immediately get $I=0$.

The OP's case is clearly a borderline/endpoint one where the above argument just happens to break down. Perhaps one can get a logarithmic improvement, by using smarter estimates.

The above simple idea is just a "Sobolev-ish"-flavored (as opposed to "Hölder-ish") adaptation of the classic proof of Hölder with exponent greater than one in 1D implies constant, by subdividing the interval $[x,y]$ into $k$ pieces and taking $k\rightarrow\infty$.